# Пиксельная мозаика из картинки

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Помогите разобраться с реализацией в C#
Необходимо сделать следующее:
1. Загрузить картинку (любого размера)
2. Изменить глубину цвета картинки в диапазоне с 8 до 32 бит (возможно выбирать 8, 16, 32)
3. Сделать из полученного изображения мозаику.

Из-за отсутствия опыта, не могу понять что делать? В каком направлении копать.
Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, вы перечислили всё что необходимо. А в чём вопрос? Опыт не имеет значения, вы сами перечислили что надо делать.

Comment: Алгоритм действия я понимаю.
Я не могу понять именно 3-й пункт. Не понимаю, что необходимо делать, чтобы из изображения получить мозаику.

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "мозаикой"?

Comment: Задачу вам ставил другой человек? Не вы это придумали? Тогда надо уточнять у него, вряд ли тут кто то имеет навык 100% угадывания того что имели ввиду... В моём понимании, это может быть и эффектом изображения, и целой игрой.

Comment: Задачу я сам себе поставил.

Comment: Вот, тогда раскройте, "мозайка" это что? Игра, эффект, или что то ещё? (Желательно показать картинку результата, который вы ожидаете)

Comment: Задачу я сам себе поставил. Что я имею ввиду под мозаикой. Мне необходимо разделить изображение на пиксели и сделать из этих пикселей кусочки мозаики. Для этого я делаю изменение глубины цвета изображения. Теперь мне необходимо разбить это изображение на кусочки (составные части мозаики).

Comment: Мозаика - это игра.

Comment: Добавил картинку в виде мозаики, что должно получиться

Comment: Ещё вопрос, каждый квадрат на этом изображении, это некая часть мозаики? И какой размер квадрата вас устроит? (16x16, 24x24, 32x32 ...)

Comment: Совершенно верно, каждый квадрат это часть мозаики. Размер квадрата... наверное 24х24

Comment: Каждый квадрат имеет в себе только один цвет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот простое и понятное решение (исправил под общее решение):

```
    private const int H_CELL = 24;
    private const int W_CELL = 24;

    private Image ConvertImage(Image source) {

        Image result = (Image)source.Clone();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(source);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {

            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y += H_CELL) {
                for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Height; x += W_CELL) {
                    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(bitmap.GetPixel(x, y));
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, W_CELL, H_CELL);
                }
            }

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Пример использования:

```
    picTo.Image = ConvertImage(picTo.Image);
```

Здесь происходит следующее - разбиваем исходное изображение на зоны размером в H_CELL/W_CELL, далее, пробегаемся по пересечениям ячеек этих зон, и извлекаем цвет, после чего, заполняем этим цветом всю зону.

[image: Скрин]

Так же, прикреплю ссылку на проект, чтобы могли посмотреть "поближе".

[Архив с проектом](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18WMsSanRrpvEP52Fq7AOhd4pjX0pzIHi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!